# Porblem with Toggle Button when using it with Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, css, html, thymeleaf

I am using an HTML5 template file with Spring MVC and thymeleaf. In the template, I'm trying to create a navigable menu using a toggle button at the top of the page.

The toggle button is displayed but when clicking on it it does not toggle the menu as expected. However when I do the same thing in HTML5 using the same code, the Toggle button works perfectly.

I do not know may be this is a Thymeleaf issue or there is anything I need to do in Thymeleaf to make this work.

Can somebody please assist my Ignorance

Here is my line of code that contains the toggle button:

```
<a href="#" th:href="@{/home}" class="logo"> <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
                <span class="logo-mini"><b>Ai</b>Admin</span> <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
                <span class="logo-lg"><b>Ai</b>Admin</span>
            </a>
```

Below is my CSS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/plugins/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/dist/css/aiAdmin.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/plugins/morris/morris.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css}" />
```

and below is Javascript:

```
<script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/jQuery/dist/jQuery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugin/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/raphael/raphael.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/morris/morris.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/moment/min/moment.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/plugins/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/dist/js/aiadmin.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/dist/js/aiadmin.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/dist/js/display.js}"></script>
```

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a verifiable and working example that people can actually debug.

Comment: Thank you Robert Wade for the response. I will update the code

Answer (score 0):

With what you provided did you specify in the HTML tag a valid tag in order for the browser to interpret your template?

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"></html>
```

Also if you wanted to make the template HTML5 compliant you can update your thymeleaf attributes to a data prefix which allows HTML5 to interpret your template and you can leave the html tag as standard.

```
 <html></html>

 <a href="#" data-th-href="@{/home}" class="logo">
```

Either option should work

Comment: Thank you @23rharris. However this solution does not work. I have tried it on many time. And this work on ordinary HTML.

Comment: Yeah np! If you're still stuck provide a little more detail on your answer to see if we could help you out a little more